# How to sum values from two different variables in seaborn countplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to make a countplot but for each row, instead of counting only 'Kidhome' variable or 'Teenhome' variable i want it to sum both for each line so that i get the total numer of childre regardless if they are teenager or kids.
I have the following code:

```
sns.countplot(y = df.sum('Kidhome', 'Teenhome'), hue = 'Marital_Status', data = df)
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your dataframe is something like this

```
data = {'Kidhome': np.random.randint(25, size=25),
        'Teenhome': np.random.randint(25, size=25),
        'Marital_Status': np.random.randint(2, size=25)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

You can get the total number like this:

```
sns.countplot(y=df['Kidhome'] + df['Teenhome'], hue='Marital_Status', data=df)
```

[image: countplot]